# Different password for windows 8 login and associated microsoft account

Tags: windows-8

I want to use KeePass to create a 50 char password for my Microsoft account, but I also want a password when I login to my laptop, is it possible to have 2 different sets of passwords for those 2?

Comment: You can use 4 digit PIN to unlock your laptop, of course that isn't as secure as your password. [Link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ewan/archive/2012/07/06/tip-o-the-week-123-windows-8-sign-in-with-pic-amp-pin.aspx) on how to setup a PIN.

Comment: Nice option, but its rather unsecure as its pretty easy to overlook 4 digits, and must be pretty easy to bruteforce even by hand unless there is a number of attempts before you need to enter master password